# Is it possible to be type safe when using update in firestore?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, typescript-typings

Currently when updating a document specific fields, we can use dot notation syntax. But unfortunately, it's a string and makes it not utilise the power of typescript.

```
await admin.firestore().doc("users/123").set({ 'address.street' : 'street name' }, {merge : true});
```

Here, user has a class defined with its properties but there is no way here to make sure address.street is a valid key path of User class.

Is there any way I can impose type checks so that typescript compiler throws an error when wrong property keys are being used when passing in dot notation?

PS: This might be not specific to firestore but to typescript in general, but firestore's usage is the right example in this context.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  It's up to you to identify the correct key using its field path (using dot notation).  The compiler isn't going to be able to verify the contents of that field path string.  The string is only going to be interpreted on the Firestore server side in order to actually place the given data in the document.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

it is possible, use this library https://firelordjs.com/quick_start/

I am the author,

the library has a very deep type system, can handle all types in all operations regardless of how deeply nested your data type is

it is virtually impossible to make typing mistakes with it

currently only the web version is available, the admin version probably arrive in 2 or 3 months (it is not easy to make this thing)

support @firebase/rules-unit-testing